# A book to learn special relativity with a group approach

Tags: special-relativity, resource-recommendations, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry

I am looking for a synthetic book that teach special relativity **from sratch** with a group approach (a mathematical approach).

I precise that I'm NOT looking for a very rigorous approach in math, but I want to learn special relativity with the mathematical formalism used in QFT, so I need to learn properties on Lorentz matrices for example.

In fact I had courses on relativity in a "non-mathematical approach", by this I mean that we didn't talked so much about the Lorentz group for example but we just used Lorentz boost to explain phenomenons. But these courses weren't really good and I would like to learn it again from scratch because I feel that I didn't understood the theory well enough.

Comment: I recomend *The Geometry of Minkowski Spacetime* by Gregory Naber. It certainly follows the group approach and starts from scratch. On the other hand it does focus on rigorous math to some extent, while it motivates the mathematical structures with physical considerations.

Comment: I'm not sure Naber's book is quite what you're looking for, but it's certainly a very cohesive and readable exposition of the material.

Comment: I took a look to the book you recommended. It is too mathematical for me I think. I'm really looking for a group approach of the theory but not a mathematical course.

Comment: (The book is too much : "Definition, Theorem, Lemma" etc if you see what I mean). I'm looking for a book for physicist BUT with a group approach.

Comment: Have you looked at _Relativity, Groups, Particles: Special Relativity and Relativistic Symmetry_  by Roman U. Sexl, Helmuth K. Urbantke?

Comment: I took a look to your book. It is closer to what I'm looking for. It is the nice spirit but maybe not synthetic enough. If someone has something in the same spirit but more synthetic it would be really nice. (I know, I am demanding :p )

Comment: Without more specifics or examples, these are likely my last suggestions: _Classical Fields, Particles and the Theory of Relativity_ by Davis, 
_The Classical Dynamics of Particles: Galilean and Lorentz Relativity_ by Mann, and
_Special Relativity_ by Tsamparlis.